# Building Thingsboard from source on Windows

Tags: thingsboard

I have a problem building Thingsboard from source on Windows:

[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit 
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
[WARNING] npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)

Exactly compiling with maven and npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's to change the GitHub URL

```
"angular-fullscreen": "git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git#master",
"mdPickers": "git://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers.git#0.7.5"
```

to

```
"angular-fullscreen": "https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git#master",
"mdPickers": "https://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers#0.7.5"
```

and

```
"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
```

Comment: [INFO] Thingsboard Server Application ..................... SUCCESS [08:30 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13:18 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-07T11:46:44-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 79M/830M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: This is actually a workaround. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Thingsboard build is tested on Linux machines.
You are able to run Thingsboard on Windows using Docker.
We will add support of the build on Windows in next release.